# Google tag assistant connects to domain but can't find tag

Tags: google-tag-manager, gtag.js

I'm trying to use the Tag Assistant Companion extension to see if tags work. As you can see in the screenshots below, it connects to the site but can't find any tags.

The site is hosted in Webflow.

Not sure what the problem is.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-NS9ZQH2');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NS9ZQH2"
height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

[image: Debug data]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 3]